# How to make a stretchy rig work correctly in game

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, unity, rigify

I need to figure out a way of exporting a character with a stretchy rig into a game engine called 'unity'.

The rig that i have is a slightly modified Pitchipoy rig, but the same problem is in Rigify. After trying to export the mesh weighted to the deform bones on the pitchipoy rig, i found that while most of the bones stay in place, the neck and face bones in particular acted erratically.

In order to try and fix this, my best idea was to make a separate rig that follows the control rig. I just took the meta rig, subdivided the arm and leg bones and added an origin bone. I weighted the mesh to this new rig and called it a 'Bind rig'.

In order to export animation to a game engine like unity, animation must be baked. I went through every bone and gave it a copy transformations constraint.
During animation this looks fine, but since games don't deal with constraints like blender does, i remove them after baking and animating the bind rig. But if you just remove them without fiddling with the inherent transforms of each bone, you get the following result.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

When the bind bones are constrained, the inherent transforms are overriden. But
without a forced constraint, it's combining each individual scale with the scale of it's parent bone, and the result is not ideal. You can fix this within blender by removing inherent scaling on each bone, but i have no idea how to do this within unity. So i guess the best thing i can do is try to find a way to get the bind bones to divide the scale, but how? Or perhaps there's a smarter way to do it...

[HERE IS THE BLEND FILE](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/549636125df91878eec6ef9f/55d3e41f8b10e9531e94fb92/ca199dd01425e96178a4c61ea2175e07/Characters_Plumber_rig.blend)

Please note that this blend file should not be used for any purpose other than for use specific to this post.

Comment: Did you check the weight of each bone?

Comment: Okay so I opened the blender file and I think their are way too many bones, but if you do not want to use shape keys, maybe adding more vertices or loop cuts will solve your problem?

Comment: @KeshaWilson  Are you talking about the weight of constraints? because i don't think the bind weights are the problem. I'm not really concerned about the bone count. I also understand that there is weighting issues, but I'm just trying to get the character into the game looking *OK* with a normal run cycle. And at some point i'll fix it, no problems. 

But mainly the thing that is going wrong is that the bind armature is not following the control rig. In theory a rig that only contains bone weight deformations should work fine in a game.